# How to get axios work within a node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to do an api call with axios within a node.js app. I can get axios work outside node.js by having the function in an app.js file and linking this to an html file. However, I can't seem to get it to work within a node.js environment. Right now I have the api in a file called "weather.js" within a controllers folder.

When I call this function from the console it says that getWeather is not defined. I can get this function to work outside a Node.js environment.

```
const axios = require('axios');

function getWeather(lat, long) {
    const key = OPEN_WEATHER_KEY;
    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
          lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${key}&units=imperial`;

    axios
   .get(url)
   .then(function (response) {
     // handle success
     console.log(response);
     console.log(response.data.name);
     console.log(response.data.main.temp);
     console.log(response.data.weather[0].description);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
   })
   .then(function () {
      // always executed
  });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem about Axios. Maybe you didn't properly import weather.js in your main file

Comment: So I would need to import the function into my index.js?

Comment: Yes, if the function is in weather.js, you should import it within index.js.

Comment: "When I call this function from the console" — Which console? Do you mean the Node.js REPL? Or are you talking about a browser-side Console?

Comment: Unlike the browser, functions you define in nodejs are not automatically global.  All nodejs code is inside a module file and to use any of that code in another module, you need to export the function and then in the other file, you need to import it.  Please read about how import and export work in nodejs as explaining the whole concept would be better done by reading tutorials and instructional material rather than an answer here.  Once educated, you can come back and ask a more specific question if you get stuck on something.